# How to connect signal in QML existing on the object set with setContextObject

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I can not figure out how to connect to a signal in an object set as ContextObject, If it had been set as a ContextProperty it would have been possible to create a Connections{} element using the context property name for "target:". But what is the name of the ContextObject object?

I have a QObject like this:

```
class Model : public QObject
{
       Q_OBJECT
       Q_PROPERTY(bool featureActive READ featureActive NOTIFY featureActiveChanged)
...
```

I set it as the ContextObject for my view like this:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Model>("model_import_name", 1, 0, "Model");
...->rootContext()->setContextObject(model);
```

In the QML i can access the property through the property name, but can not figure out how to react on the changed signal:
*.qml:

```
import model_import_name 1.0
...
visible: featureActive // Can access the getter! Great!

 // Runtime error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onFeatureActiveChanged"
onFeatureActiveChanged: { <do something> } 

// Runtime error: QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent 
//property "onFeatureActiveChanged"
Connections{
    target: this
    onFeatureActiveChanged: {
        <do something>
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Is there a (secret?) property name for the ContextObject? There are of course workarounds (onVisibleChange, onQmlDummyVariableBoundToFeatureActiveChanged etc) but isn't there a real way to connect to such a signal?

Comment: I think the capitalization of the word 'Feature' is your issue. The signal name is not capitalized but in the connections object it is

Comment: This is how the Qt "magic" works. property change signals are presented to qml as "on" + [capitalized]<signalname>. If I use a context property instead of a context object this is how it would be accessed. Kuba Ober has been kind to give a modified example of how it looks like when using a context property (which we agree works fine). The problem is that, if we go back to KubaObers example code but using contextobject in the c++, removing the "model." in the "visible:" binding works as expected, but removing "model." in the onChanged connection does not.